# pre tag- text overflows the box

Tags: html, css, text, tags, pre

I have applied the following style to the `pre` element:

```
pre {
     background-color: #FFFFCC;
     border: 2px dashed #FF6666;
     padding-top: 7px;
     padding-bottom: 8px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     float: none;
     padding-right: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
    }
```

The text overflows the box.
When I applied the `float:right` property the box behaved as expected but in large screens the rest floated around the box naturally. Not happy. EDIT2 : I made it (but for ie6), using float + clear. I have posted [another question on the new bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358129/ie6-weird-h3-div-behavior-no-right-margin-bug-in-ff)

I am new to CSS and HTML - I am sure there is a simple solution. Please help.
:(

**EDIT** : closer to the mark :

```
pre {
     background-color: #FFFFCC;
     border: 2px dashed #FF6666;
     padding-top: 7px;
     padding-bottom: 8px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-right: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
     white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
```

This one displays exactly as I want in ie6 - in ff 3.5 the text wraps - I know this is is the way it should be - but how can I carry the ie behavior to ff ?

Images for the styled pre tag with `white-space: pre;`

ie6 : https://i1032.photobucket.com/albums/a406/dardanov/ie6pre.jpg

[image]

ff 3.5 : https://i1032.photobucket.com/albums/a406/dardanov/ff35pre.jpg

[image]

for `white-space: pre-wrap;` firefox wraps and ie stays the same. How can I get the ie behavior (autoexpanding of the code box) in ff ?

**EDIT2** : see answer below

Comment: Why are you using a PRE tag anyway? Why not a DIV with your desired CSS that contains (if necessary) a PRE tag that holds the text with your presumably desirable rigid whitespace intact?

Comment: And what this css would be ? I want the box to shrink or widen according to the text inside it. I will try and post back.

Comment: Did try the div approach with the "closer to the mark code" attached as a class style. Still the text wraps in ff. So is there a way for the box to shrink or widen with the text while pre-formatted? The white-space: pre; has the text overflow the box unfortunately.

Comment: `overflow-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;`. It's time to really drop IE... If you found this having **vertical** overflow issues - check if your parent element has `display: flex;` ... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I made it* (ff 3.5, opera 10, ie8 but not ie6 (ie7 not tested))

I wrapped the different sections in div tags styled as seen below -in ie6 the divs display with small width (when they include a h3 tag), the pre tag is not affected. In the other browsers the divs shrink with the page - while the pre tag is not affected also. Another small issue I'm having is the right margin not displaying in the pre tag. I have posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358129/ie6-weird-h3-div-behavior-no-right-margin-bug-in-ff) on these

So the structure of the html is :

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>...</div>   //this div is ok in ie
  <div><h3>Title...</h3>...</div>    //this div is shrunken
  ...
  <div><h3>Title...</h3>...</div>    //this div is shrunken
  <pre></pre>
  <div><h3>Title...</h3>...</div>    //this div is shrunken
  ...
  <div><h3>Title...</h3>...</div>    //this div is shrunken
 </body>
<html>
```

styled as :

```
pre {
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    border: 2px dashed #FF6666;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
div {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Just add this to your css

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to display code/text contained within a box, and that code cannot wrap (unless such wraps, or carriage-returns/line-feeds/etc are present in the code/text itself). You also want the containing element to increase its horizontal dimension in order to expand to the required width of the text/code?

So if your text had 20 characters as its longest line, your `<pre>` would be at least 20 characters in width, if the text had 200 characters for the longest line then it should stretch to accommodate the 200 characters?

If these assumptions are correct, then you can't -without javascript, at least- do what you want to do, since it would require setting the width of the parent based on the width of its child element. Unfortunately CSS cascades down the DOM, and in one-way only.

The best you could do, without JS, is to add:

`overflow: scroll; /* or auto */`

or:

`overflow-x: scroll;`

to your CSS, which would maintain the width of the `<pre>`, but allow for scrolling to allow for the longest lines to remain un-wrapped.

If I've misunderstood your question, please raise a comment, and I'll do what I can to address your question more usefully.

Comment: Thank you ! You read it correctly.  So the behavior of ie is a bug ? Cause it is the only bug I know of worth reproducing. I am not for the overflow property - I need js to reproduce the ie bug ?

Comment: Any documentation (links) for the bug would be very useful btw.
Thanks (also for the edits)

Comment: And an explanation as to why float:left does the job !?
 I will be experimenting with this and clear - maybe I 'll have it my way after all :)

Comment: I'm unsure as to why `float: left` does the job, it might be because `float` takes the element out of the document's flow and removes the constraint for the element to inherit its parents' width? But this is just a guess and I certainly can't back it up with evidence. If others can correct me I'd be interested to know.

Comment: I wrapped the sections of the readme in divs floated to the left and ` clear:both ` and it works exactly as I want in ff 3.5 and opera 10 - but now ie6 restricts the width of the divs considerably (?!) Any fix ?

Comment: Update your question (or, possibly, consider starting a new question if you feel it merits doing so) with where you're at now, and I'll have a proper look when I get a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the semi-colon issue, the one important thing the pre tag does is set the CSS [white-space property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp) to "nowrap" (or "pre" I suppose, but that just confuses things), so it's working exactly as it should. If yo want to stop it from working like that, set "nowrap: normal;". However, that makes the pre element work like every other element instead of how it's intended to work, which might confuse other people working with you. Why not just use a div element? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Display some code.
I dont want it to wrap, I want the yellow (#FFFFCC) box to have the dimensions of the text. If I set the float property this is what happens. As it is I get a fixed width box and the comments of the code overflow. Ugly. I don't want to use scrolling either.
Any idea ?

Comment: Actually I set the white-space property to nowrap in dreamweaver and it displays nice, but in firefox (3.5) I see a huge line of text and the box has still fixed width. Same in ie6 but the box has the width of the line. Welcome to css I guess.
Help

Comment: I set the white-space property to pre-wrap : in dreamweaver (CS3) the text still overflows but in ie6 I got what I wanted. In firefox the text wraps but no more overflows. Now is there a way to get the ie6 picture (due to some bug probably) over to ff ?

Comment: Do you have a url we can look at?

Comment: Uploaded images pz have a look :)

Comment: I'm with ricebowl: from what you've said, you can't do what you want with a purely CSS solution.